# IOS 13 can show 4 camera previews at the same time?

Tags: ios13, multi-camera-api

I know that IOS13 can display 2 camera previews simultaneously on iPhone 11 Pro and above.  I saw the DoubleTake app where they are showing live preview from all the 4 cameras (three back cameras and one front camera).  Any pointer on how this can be achieved?

[image: camera selection in DoubleTake app]

The above screen shot shows the camera selection part in their app.  All the 4 videos are simultaneously showing live.  IOS13 supports 2 cameras active at a time on iPhone 11 Pro.  How can I display all 4 cameras in my app as seen in this screen?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open API for this. You can do it with `AVCaptureMultiCamSession`, which is `a capture session that supports simultaneous capture from multiple inputs of the same media type`.

It's a lot of code. For details, pls check out these WWDC 2019 sessions:

- [Introducing Multi-Camera Capture for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/249)
- [Advances in Camera Capture & Photo Segmentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/225)

And there an excellent [sample code project associated with it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avmulticampip_capturing_from_multiple_cameras).

Comment: Thanks.  I have seen those presentations and sample code.  They provide solutions to capture and display max 2 cameras at a time.  I am looking for a solution to show all the 4 cameras not-so-good-guality in one screen for user to pick 2 out of the 4 cameras.  This is done in the DoubleTake app.